# How to align the button text top instead of center?

Tags: html, css

My button design like the below.

```
<button class="button" style="vertical-align: top; margin-top: 0px; height: 15px"  onclick="ShowTaskDetails()">
    <%: request.Id%> 
</button>
```

If button has a height of 15px, then the button text not visible in some browsers - it is displayed under the button. I need to display the button text top of the button. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There a probably a few ways to do this but off the top of my head. You could wrap the text in a `<span>` and then position it inside.

### HTML:

```
<button>
    <span>Test</span>
</button>
```

### CSS:

```
button {
    height:35px;
}
span {
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Like I said there a probably other ways to do this. This is for a fixed button height, if your button does not have a fixed height then do not use this.

OP, you should explain what's happening better then you have. The text is just missing? If the button has a fixed height and the correct `font-size` it will show in **ALL** browsers. Pushing the text to the top is not a good option. You should find what is causing the button to display wrong. Try posting more relevant code so we can have a look.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SBuRL/)

**Note:** The height is set to `35px` in mine to show the text is at the top. Hard to show on a `15px` height button. Code is easy to change to work for `15px`.

Comment: Cleaner way than mine :) Probably the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Explain the downvote - Don't just downvote everyone's and not say what is wrong with the answer.

Comment: I think someone raged and downvoted all the answers, I voted your answer up.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

It's the solution, but you will have to play around:

```
.button{
    margin-top: 0px;
    height:15px;
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:6px;
}
```

[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/5HdZ2/)

Comment: Why is this an answer when you just said "It's not the solution".

Comment: Here you will have to adjust the font size and line-height to get the result you want.

Comment: Get the text to the top using the way you just said. Then post a demo.

Comment: @Ruddy because it's morning and i'm still dreaming.. haha.. just corrected the text.

Comment: lol it's morning and you're dreaming, that's why you're voting down others?

Comment: The question has clearly mentioned the height. So T'm sure that changing the height can't be the solution @Nix

Comment: Thanks @Nik. I guess someone is playing around down-voting here for fun but not for providing correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

---

Set static height for the button and add padding: 0px 10px 10px;

```
<button  class="button"  style="padding: 0px 10px 10px; height:30px""> Button text </button>
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cJ6bD/2/

Comment: button's height: 15px.

Comment: It will work with height 15px as well, he'll need to reduce font size.

Comment: and so was my answer. changing font height with line-height to set the text appear correctly in the button.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the line-height to 1px (or 6px as @CodeMonk did) will place the text at the top of the button.

Answer (score -1):

See that: http://jsfiddle.net/5HdZ2/2/

It's pretty ugly : I wrap the text into a `span.txt` and duplicate it as `span.hidden`.

The hidden span is there to keep the size of the button. Then, the .txt is absolutely positionned, so you can put it where you want.

In my opinion, it's the only solution that will work in all cases (crossbrowser, whatever the button size). But yeah, it's ugly.

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian I would guess they did the same thing as me. Made the height bigger to show that it is at the top.  Its not hard to change the code to work for `15px`.

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian 30px or 15px is the same, it works in both case. Stop raging please.

Comment: @enguerranws i didnt rag here..!! ws just saying to you.!!